# find string in block using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to search the word 'Digital Commerce' in the block of div which is generated in drupal.I have tried to search to find the word and get  the class name of the div.If the word 'Digital Commerce' is in class 'views-row-2' I want to get the class name 'views-row views-row-2 views-row-even' using jquery.The below html code is generated in drupal. I want to search the word in both list item div.

```js
$('#tabsSlider .carousel-inner li:contains("Digital Commerce")').each(function() {
  $(this).find('div').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.tabSection a').css('color', 'red !important');
    var className = $(this).find('.tabSection a').attr('class');
    console.log(className);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel slide" id="tabsSlider">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Consulting</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/digital-commerce">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Digital Commerce</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/customer-portals">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Customer Portals</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/internal-collaboration-platform" class="">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Internal Collaboration Platform </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/business-process-automation">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Business Process Automation</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item"> //same as first list</li>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#tabsSlider" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#tabsSlider" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#tabsSlider .carousel-inner li div:contains("Digital Commerce")').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.tabSection a').css('color', 'red');
    var className = $(this).closest('.tabSection').parent().attr('class');
    console.log(className);
});


$('#tabsSlider a').filter(function() {
    var qwe = $(this).attr("href");
    
    return qwe.indexOf("internal-collaboration-platform") > -1
}).css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel slide" id="tabsSlider">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Consulting</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/digital-commerce">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Digital Commerce</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/customer-portals">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Customer Portals</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/internal-collaboration-platform" class="">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Internal Collaboration Platform </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
        <div class="tabSection col-md-2">
          <a href="test/portals-content-management/business-process-automation">
            <div class="tabTitle">
              <div class="field-content">Business Process Automation</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item"> //same as first list</li>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#tabsSlider" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#tabsSlider" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

1. Use `div:contains()` selector to select the div that contains that text
2. Use `.closest()` to get the anchor and the div that is related to that div

Comment: I have urlParameter='Digital Commerce'; Shall I use $('#tabsSlider .carousel-inner li div:contains("'+urlParameter[3]+'")')

Comment: @user3386779 urlParameter only

Comment: the above snippet is not working for the work 'internal-collaboration-platform' in fourth view href

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145692/discussion-between-user3386779-and-guradio).